# Can't install apps on SD card

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage

I'v got the Alcatel One Touch Pop C9
It has not much space by itself, thats why I use a SD card.
I tried to set the SD card as default install.
But everytime I want to install something I get the error that I dont have enough space and first need to delete someting.

Can somone help me please?

With Kind Regards,

Vlusion

Comment: Some apps can't be installed on the SD card. What apps are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

No app can be installed on SD card if it isn't set as adoptable. Some apps can store it's data but thar isn't much space if you want to really move apps to SD use app like link2sd, but your phone has to be rooted.

Comment: Ok, do you know a good root app?

Comment: @Vlusion Hmm, you can try this: https://youtu.be/ykMbJ9EbNTc

Comment: ALready done xD, but It just installs crap and it was still not rooted

Comment: @Vlusion then try apps like kingroot and such, but be carefull they may screw up phone, so do a research first, there must be a way to root